# Word for selecting the most appropriate word

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word to describe selecting the absolute best word to use in a sentence? This is a problem for writers.

Comment: What's the question again?

Answer (score 4):

*[Mot juste](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mot-juste)* means the exact, appropriate word.

Comment: Given these are actually ***two*** (French) words, perhaps we should say the answer is *the/les [mots justes*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/mots+justes) :)

Comment: So why can't he simply use *the right word* since *mot juste* means  *the right word*?

Comment: _Mot juste_ is better.

Answer (score 0):

There's the French-origin word "[**mot juste**](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/mot-juste)", which, as mentioned in [earlier answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/144796/50044) is defined by ODO as

> The exact, appropriate word

If it's the process of choosing words, irrespective of them being good or bad, call it "wording", or "phrasing". Definitions from M-W:

[**Wording**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wording)

> the way in which something is said or written : the words that are used to say something

[**Phrasing**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/phrasing)

> the way something is expressed in words : the particular words or the order of words that are used to express something

So, a sentence can be [**poorly**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poorly) worded or phrased. Or, perhaps, it can be [**wordy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wordy)

Or it can be [**clear**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clearly), [**concise**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/concise), or [**properly**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/properly) worded.